# How to stop screen update loops without deadlocks?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

I have a Windows form created in .net with some asynchronous loops that are updating GUI components. Each update from the other thread requires a:

```
Private Sub UpdateGUI(value As String)
  Me.Invoke(
   Sub()
      Control.Text = value
    End Sub))
End Sub
```

While the calling loop begins life with:

```
m_UpdaterThread = System.threading.Tasks.Task.Run(
  Sub()
    While Not m_Closing
      UpdateGUI(value.ToString)
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End While
  End Sub))
```

However I now want to gracefully close the program, and intercepting the `OnClosing` event and providing a `m_Closing = True` and a, `m_UpdaterThread.Wait()` causes a deadlock, with the GUI updater waiting to perform its operation on the GUI thread while the GUI thread waits for it to finish. What is the better model for this? How can I wait on a thread that is waiting on the special GUI thread?

**Update: Possible solution**

The exception thrown if I do not wait on the loop is that I cannot access as disposed member. Changing the `UpdateGUI` to invoke on the concerned control seems to have resolved any exceptions.

```
Private Sub UpdateGUI(value As String)
  Control.Invoke(
   Sub()
      Control.Text = value
    End Sub))
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use a regular old TIMER on your Form?

Comment: Seems like there a few potentially better ways to handle this situation.  Maybe a background worker might be a more suitable solution?

Comment: Is your actual code/program more complicated than the posted code?  The code above could be handled by a simple Timer.  Give more DETAILS...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, yes the application is extensive, the above examples are boiling down the key issue. I'm not so curious about alternatives or workarounds, more about the coneptual question of how to manage asynchronous calls to the GUI thread that seem impossible to handle without much more rigorous thread management.

Comment: @Hursey The background worker is indeed an alternative, how does it handle the situation differently that might avoid this issue?

Comment: @JCollins Probably a bit of broad question for a comment.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1 Should get you started